# Comparison between groups

Tags: p-value, kruskal-wallis-test, bonferroni

I have to compare three groups. Three measurements using 3 different methods on the same subjects.
The variables are not normal, and the measures concern the same people, so dependent samples. I can use Kruskal-Wallis?
I can use Wilcoxon post analysis with Bonferroni correction?
How can I use the Bonferroni correction in R? Can I have examples?

Comment: I would advise usage of a specific post-hoc test such as Dunn's or Nemenyi test which can be found in `PMCMR` package.

Comment: _Thank you, but for the comparison of the three groups?_

Comment: There are no reasons to use post-hoc test for less than 3 groups. Both Dunn's test  and Nemenyi test are working perfectly fine with 3 and more groups.

Answer (score 1):

It seems some misunderstanding have arose in comments, so here is an answer.

**Why we shouldn't use Wilcoxon test as post-hoc?**

Pairwise Wilcox-Mann-whitney test doesn't take into account ranks from Kruskal-Wallis test, it creates it's own. On the other side [Dunn's test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/dunn-test/info) use group ranking from KW test.

**Example with R:**

```
set.seed(pi)
df <- data.frame(val = c(runif(15,  0, 15),
                         runif(15,  0, 15),
                         runif(15, 10, 20)),
                 grp = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), each = 15))

kruskal.test(val ~ grp, df)

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  val by grp
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 22.045, df = 2, p-value = 1.633e-05
```

So Kruskal-Wallis test tells us that there is statistically significant differences between groups. But we need to run Dunn's test to know between which pairs of group we have difference .

```
require(PMCMR)
posthoc.kruskal.dunn.test(val ~ grp, df)

    Pairwise comparisons using Dunn's-test for multiple 
                         comparisons of independent samples 

data:  val by grp 

  A       B      
B 0.96674 -      
C 0.00013 0.00013

P value adjustment method: holm
```

And we can conclude that group C is different from A and B.

**Edit**

Okey, I missed part about dependent samples.

In case of dependent samples Friedman test with appropriate post-hoc (Conover test in `PMCMR` for example) should be used. But general approach (just with correct tests) I showed above is still applicable.

Comment: ok but I know that the Kruskal wallis method is not used when the samples are dependent

Comment: the Friedman test can be applied in the case of groups with different numerosity?